# MIN value from data set and sum

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data:

```
ID  DUE         AMT
4   2018-03-10  335.75
3   2018-04-10  334.75
1   2018-05-10  333.75
2   2018-06-10  332.75
```

I need to extract:

1. least due (03-10)
2. amt for least due (335.75)
3. sum of amt column.

Could it be done in single query?

Comment: Kindly share your sample query. You must try it at least once before asking others

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can try using analytic functions here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ID, DUE, AMOUNT,
        SUM(AMOUNT) OVER () AS TOTALAMOUNT,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DUE) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT ID, DUE, AMOUNT, TOTALAMOUNT
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: least due is missing in this query

Comment: No it's not.  You misunderstand my query.

Comment: sorry from my side

Comment: Slightly faster than keep (dense_rank..) from answer above. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Try keep dense rank:

```
with tt as (
  select 4 id, date '2018-03-10' due, 335.75 amt from dual union all
  select 3 id, date '2018-04-10' due, 334.75 amt from dual union all
  select 1 id, date '2018-05-10' due, 333.75 amt from dual union all
  select 2 id, date '2018-06-10' due, 332.75 amt from dual
)
select min(due) least_due,
       min(amt) keep (dense_rank first order by due) amt_for_least_due,
       sum(amt) sum_amt
from   tt
```